# How to get value in nodes with specific attribute in XML by using python3?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am a Python beginner. Now I am dealing with XML and [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).
I am working on the example xml below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I'd like to get the value inside the country tag with a specific attribute.
For example,

> I wan to get rank, year and gdppc where country name = "Singapore"

I tried, but have no idea how to do it.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This looks like the tutorial in the [etree documentation] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  Have you tried working through the code there?  Were you able to get the parser running, and did you run the example that prints the names and ranks of all countries?  Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just write code that loops through the results of an XML parser? (That wouldn't be the most efficient way of doing it, but it would work.)

Answer (score 0):

Read the [XPath examples from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example). That already shows how to extract the year.

```
values = ['rank', 'year', 'gdppc']
for v in values:
    print(v, root.findall(".//*[@name='Singapore']/{}".format(v))[0].text)
```

Outputs

```
rank 4
year 2011
gdppc 59900
```